# Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): This name contains uppercase characters, which is not allowed.

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, xhtml-1.0-strict

I wrote this code in Visual Studio but i am receiving this  error.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="281">
             <tr>
                 <td width="135">
                     <asp:Label ID="lbluyeadi" runat="server" Text="Üye Adı :"></asp:Label>
                 </td>
                 <td Width="126">
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtuyeadi" runat="server" width="108px"></asp:TextBox>
                 </td>
             </tr>
```

The error's message is 
"Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute 'width' is considered outdated. A newer construct is recommended."

But when I write Width instead of width , it gives me another problem which is 
"Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): This name contains uppercase characters, which is not allowed."

Comment: pass width value in css, like as <td style=" width:'135';"> hope it is help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using HTML elements in an XHTML document.

The solution is to replace the HTML element such as

```
  <td width=30%>
```

with a CSS style. The style can be inline or in an attached style sheet.

try this

```
 <td style="width:20%">
```

dont recommend styling in the code but meh XD

you should have a external style sheet it makes life alot more pleasant and is just better coding practice

hope i helped

Comment: The first one doesn't work. But to write the second one solved the problem.Thank you

Comment: Glad i helped if its correct just mark it as correct else im just hanging in the wind with a random answer and anytime @user3668628 let me know if you have more problems

Comment: I did :) Thank you very much again,I'll let you know for sure. ;)

Comment: lol thanks and no problem  bud :) anytime gave you a upvote this is a common mistake so this will help others